# How to set and disable headers in php's SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, hhvm

The SoapClient sends the HTTP header:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2085
Expect: 100-continue

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
```

I want to disable the `Expect: 100-continue`. How can I do that?

I found out that I should be able to set a custom header via:

```
class SoapClient extends \SoapClient implements HttpClientInterface

    public function __construct($pathToWSDL, array $options, LoggerInterface $logger){
        ...
        $headers = [
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
                [
                    'http' => [
                        'header' => 'SomeCustomHeader: value',
                    ],
                ]
            ),
        ];
        parent::__construct($pathToWSDL, array_merge($options, $headers));
 }
```

yet this doesn't work.

How can I set a custom header and disable certain ones?

I am also not using native php, but HipHop VM 3.12.1 (rel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [HTTP context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) indicate that the `header` option can be a string or an array of strings, and will override other given options. If you want to use a single string with multiple options, you would separate with a carriage return and newline (`\r\n`) as illustrated in the first [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/stream_context_create) example,.

So the construction would be:

```
'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
    [
        'http' => [
            'header' => "SomeCustomHeader: value\r\n".
                        "Expect: \r\n",
        ],
    ]
),
```

Or:

```
'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
    [
        'http' => [
            'header' => [
                'SomeCustomHeader: value',
                'Expect: ',
            ],
        ],
    ]
),
```

In your case though, most likely the cause is the version of HHVM you're using - this was [a bug in HHVM](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/6263) which doesn't appears to have been [fixed in 3.15.0](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/commit/eec9da990e7344af985735ec53d73325579931eb) so you might want to try upgrading your HHVM and trying again.

Comment: The [SoapHeapers](http://php.net/manual/de/class.soapheader.php) are part of the Soap Envelope (XML within the HTTP POST payload). This question is not about them. It's about the HTTP headers the SoapClient sends per default and how to adapt them.

Comment: @k0pernikus Completely correct, have removed that from the post and supplied additional detail, references and possible fix around your HHVM version.

Comment: It seems to be the HHVM bug. How do you know it was fixed in 3.15? I don't see a version reference / milestone of that commit.

Comment: @k0pernikus At the very bottom of the blue box for the commit that I've linked with the fix, you can see the branches (master), and the tagged releases (3.15.2, 3.15.1, 3.15.0) that the fix is a part of.

Comment: You sure you meant to go with single quotes for '\r\n' and not with "\r\n". Either way, for your first approach I got array to string conversion errors. The second one worked fine.

Comment: @k0pernikus absolutely correct on the quote marks (have fixed them), but glad that the second one worked for you!

Comment: I accounted you the bounty for pointing me in the direction of the hhvm bug.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, this approach would be overkill, but if you're trying to cope with an HHVM bug around `stream_context_create`, you might try completely overriding [`SoapClient::__doRequest`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php)

Something *like* this

```
public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way=0)
{
    // @note Omitted Expect: 100-continue
    $headers = [
        'Accept: */*',
        'Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip',
        'SOAPAction: ""',
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($request),
        'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue',
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($location);
    curl_setopt_array(
        $ch, [
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST           => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $request,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers,
        ]);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

I used this approach to [implement SOAP with Attachments](https://github.com/quickshiftin/soap-with-attachments/blob/master/SwASoapClient.php) and it worked great, albeit under the standard PHP interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have used `stream_context_create` in order to set some additional HTTP header. I don't know about removing one of them, but maybe you can overwrite one. So, have you tried setting an empty `Expect` header?

```
$headers = [
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(
        [
            'http' => [
                'header' => 'Expect: ',
            ],
        ]
    ),
];
```

Comment: Not yet. Will look into it to provide feedback.